# How to make vi redraw screen?

Tags: git, vim

When I use

```
git commit --amend
```

It will enter into a vi window to let me input comments for commit, the problem is the vi windows will show some dirty characters from former shell background. So I wonder how can I let vi to reload or redraw the screen to make the screen normal.

So far, I try reset terminal and Ctrl+L, it works, but I wonder is there best answer for such situation?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

If your terminal supports it, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is a common shortcut for this.

Comment: control+L seems does not work for me; I have to reset terminal first. not know why....

Comment: Not know why, after remove my .vimrc file, no it is okay.

Comment: Was your .vimrc setting 'term'? Perhaps it was setting it incorrectly.

Comment: @AlexMartelli: ctrl+L doesn't seem to work over Putty. `!redraw` is more versatile.

Comment: ctrl+l doesn't work for me, this seems dependent on your terminal.

also :redraw! seems like the works for everybody solution.

Comment: For those above mentioning <C-L> not working, I think you might have mapped the key binding to something else. In that case, just use `:redraw!`

Comment: If this does not work for you, try with `vim -u NORC` to see if it's a configuration issue.

Comment: For anybody who came here thinking this would even out the screen in split view mode..., see https://superuser.com/a/257115/118989.

Comment: @DebugXYZ For me it’s the other way round: `:redraw!` does nothing — but Ctrl-L works (iTerm with tmux on macOS).

Answer (score 331):

To force a screen refresh

```
:redraw!
```

Answer (score 6):

In Vi both of these are redraw:

- ^R ( does not work with VT100 type terminals )
- ^L ( does not work with Televideo terminals )

From http://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html#A1.4 (dead link; see [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150316034341/http://www.cs.rit.edu/~cslab/vi.html))

As noted in the comments Vim now uses ^R for redo and ^L alone for redraw.

Comment: Isn't ^R redo? ^L works for me for redrawing the screen.

Comment: @Geremia Depends on terminal type apparently, ^L is probably more common by far.

Comment: In vim, ^R is always redo.