# Open URL under cursor in Vim with browser

Tags: vim

I'm using Twitvim for the first time. Seeing all the URLs in there made me wonder, is there any way to open the URL under the cursor in your favorite browser or a specified one?

Comment: under text cursor or mouse cursor?

Comment: text cursor ... but if you know a way to do under the mouse cursor that would be cool too

Comment: middle mouse button click on a link in vim has always worked for me, I don't know how, though

Comment: middle click to open is likely a feature of the terminal, not vim.

Comment: Note that `gx` appears utterly broken in vim 8.2 due to a bug: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22459/gx-doesnt-open-the-url-and-complains-netrw-no-line-in-buffer/22505#22505

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Updated: from tpope's tweet today

Press `gx`. You can customize the browser. On Gnome and Mac OS X it's already use `gnome-open`/`open`. Generally you can set `g:netrw_browsex_viewer` to anything you want.

---

Original answer:

Don't remember where I get this function. There is a bug with hash (#) in the url, but the function works well enough that I won't bother fixing it.

```
function! HandleURL()
  let s:uri = matchstr(getline("."), '[a-z]*:\/\/[^ >,;]*')
  echo s:uri
  if s:uri != ""
    silent exec "!open '".s:uri."'"
  else
    echo "No URI found in line."
  endif
endfunction
map <leader>u :call HandleURL()<cr>
```

Note: If you are not on the Mac, use `gnome-open`/`xdg-open` for Linux, or 'path to your web browser' for Windows

Comment: I think I'll use your solution :) thanks ... I do would like to see if there is a way to get only the url under the cursor, but don't know much vimscript so I'll have to work on that.

Comment: `gx` is so powerful, thanks! It also opens files with appropriate applications™.

Comment: I think it is g:netrw_browsex_viewer (w/o 'r')

Comment: I like to open a url with a ? and a # in it.  I think netrw is using cfile instead of cWORD now, so urls with '?' are not longer openable using that method.  I tried your solution here and '#' in the url would be replaced by the alternate file name.  exec "!open ".shellescape(uri, 1) seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: The aforementioned tweet is here: https://twitter.com/tpope/status/289234166770434048, just in case anyone is interested in the discussion.

Comment: I added a sort of improved version of this script here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817071/7631731 This improvements correctly handles URLs containing "#" and also keeps the vim context active.

Comment: @ChadSkeeters URLs with queries and anchors open without issues using `gx` on `nvim`. Do you use `vim`? Although paths for files with `@` in the filename don't open. Would be cool if `gx` worked with visual selection.

Answer (score 72):

If you are using Vim 7.4 or later, in normal mode, put your cursor below the URL, then click `gx`, the URL will be opened in browser automatic [image: demo operate]

Comment: how are you setting the browser to be Chrome in this example? (or whatever browser that is)

Comment: @jm3 Try [`:h netrw_gx`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-gx): 
  
    * for Windows 32 or 64, the url and FileProtocolHandler dlls are used.
    * for Gnome (with gnome-open): gnome-open is used.
    * for KDE (with kfmclient)   : kfmclient is used
    * for Mac OS X               : open is used.
    * otherwise the netrwFileHandler plugin is used.

Comment: off topic a little, but how do you record the screen into a gif? love it!

Comment: @jm3 Which using the System's default web browser

Comment: @PeterPerháč I'm using https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr to record Keyboard input, http://www.cockos.com/licecap/ to record screen as gif

Answer (score 22):

### Solution for people that unloaded `netrw`

This is a solution for people who removed `netrw`([`:help netrw-noload`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-noload)) in vim/neovim. For example, they use a different file-manager like [`vim-dirvish`](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish)

#### TLDR:

`:!open <c-r><c-a>`

or map `gx`:

`nmap gx :!open <c-r><c-a>`

---

### So just a bit of background:

I was searching for a solution to this problem too since I actually removed netrw from being loaded in vim completely and replace it with [`vim-dirvish`](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish). This plugin has around **500~ LOC**, compared to `netrw`'s **(11,000+ LOC)**.

I don't use remote editing much so `vim-dirvish` is powerful enough to manage my workflow (It's actually faster than `netrw` ~ *the author claims 2x, I feel it's faster than that - **it's really instantaneous*** ⚡) very useful on large codebase/repositories. I even tried it in a 10K file repo, listing files via `-` still instant! [Someone tested `vim-dirvish` against `Nerdtree`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILpdtL-4gv0), you can see the difference.

I dropped `vim-vinegar` too because vim-dirvish have the `-` binding anyway, and most of the configuration of `vim-vinegar` is `netrw` specifics. It's just doesn't need it. Two birds in one stone!

The beauty of this plugin is it embraces the philosophy of **VINE** (Vim is not Emacs). Where it leverages the power of other programs in the terminal to do file manipulations, instead of trying to do everything by itself. The important part is how natural these external programs interact with vim. And that is achieve by `:Shdo`, and it has a convenient key of [`.` (dot command](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish/blob/master/doc/dirvish.txt#L72-L74), which is mnemonic for the repeat command), do that on both selection or the actual line on a `vim-dirvish` buffer. And type `!rm` for remove, `!mv` for rename.

Since I disable netrw, ([`:help netrw-noload`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-noload)) I found myself reaching `gx` for time to time. I didn't want to load a plugin to get the `gx` functionality back.

---

Now for the solution, there's a binding in command mode, <kbd>ctrl-r</kbd> then <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> ([`:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-A)), to paste whatever you have in your cursor to the command line, so if you combine that with `:!xdg-open` / `:!open` (for mac), you pretty much set.

There's a reason why `:w` doesn't have normal bindings. I'm surprised most solution doesn't leverage command workflow, I use ex-command a lot, `:s`, `:g`, `:v`, `:argdo`, `:cdo`, and friends. Combining this with different modes, taps the full power of vim. So don't just stay in one mode, try to leverage the full power of vim.

#### So the full workflow. While you have your cursor on top of the url, is just a single step:

`:!open <c-r><c-a>`

Notice the `!` which indicates leveraging the power of external programs outside of vim. **VINE**!

If you want the `gx` functionality back, you can just map using the same command:

- `nmap gx :!open <c-r><c-a>`

I like to silent my bindings, so adding `<silent>` and `:sil` will do the trick ([`:help :map-silent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-silent))

`nmap <silent>gx :sil !open <c-r><c-a><cr>`

#### Note on platform-specific programs to open a url:

1. Mac has `:!open`
2. Linux has `:!xdg-open`
3. Windows (WSL2) has `:!wslview`

I use all three platforms and they work great. You can just use one of them for your vim bindings, eg. `:!open` and just alias in your `bashrc/zshrc/fish config` the `open` command to whatever platform-specific program you have.

eg. `alias open = wslview`

That way, my `vimrc` stays platform-agnostic, and I'll just deal with the inconsistencies via `bashrc/zshrc/fish config`.

Comment: On plain Windows it is `start`

Comment: Any idea how to support makrdown links? The `<c-r><c-a>` approach breaks for links like `[Example page](https://example.com)`.

Comment: just curious. when you removed netrw. did you feel any improvment in speed? and did it impact any other plugins (i.e. fzf etc.. which might use netrw)?

Comment: @mirageglobe startup time is faster since it's not loading netrw anymore :)

Comment: @UltraMaster if you are using Windows Terminal you can open external links by ctrl + clicking the link.

Answer (score 10):

I use this script to search gooogle for `keyword` under cursor:

```
nmap <leader>g :call Google()<CR>
fun! Google()
    let keyword = expand("<cword>")
    let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . keyword
    let path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/"
    exec 'silent !"' . path . 'firefox.exe" ' . url
endfun
```

You should use `getline('.')` and `matchstr()` to extract url under cursor. The rest is the same.

Comment: I think this will point me to the solution I'm looking for eventually ... plus this function will become very handy. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for awesome sharing. I'll use it to make a translation in google translate.

Answer (score 3):

Add following line to .vimrc file:

```
nmap <leader><space> yiW:!xdg-open <c-r>" &<cr>
```

So in normal mode it pressing \ it selects current word and open it as address in web browser.

Leader by default is \ (but I've mapped it to , with `let mapleader = ","`). Similarly, using imap you can map some key sequence in insert mode (but then, if it is 2 key sequence, it probably will override some default behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so using the answers from @tungd and @kev and a little research I ended up with this script, which works just the way I need to. Like @tungd said the # can give a problem if inside a url but I'm cool with that, if anyone has a better expression for the url then it will be welcomed.

```
function! OpenUrlUnderCursor()
    let path="/Applications/Safari.app"
    execute "normal BvEy"
    let url=matchstr(@0, '[a-z]*:\/\/[^ >,;]*')
    if url != ""
        silent exec "!open -a ".path." '".url."'" | redraw! 
        echo "opened ".url
    else
        echo "No URL under cursor."
    endif
endfunction
nmap <leader>o :call OpenUrlUnderCursor()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sort of improved version of the script originally proposed by @tungd here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459366/7631731.
Keeps vim context and handles correctly URLS containing "#".

```
function! HandleURL()
  let s:uri = matchstr(getline("."), '[a-z]*:\/\/[^ >,;()]*')
  let s:uri = shellescape(s:uri, 1)
  echom s:uri
  if s:uri != ""
    silent exec "!open '".s:uri."'"
    :redraw!
  else
    echo "No URI found in line."
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>w :call HandleURL()<CR>¬
```

Comment: i'm new to vim. these code shall be added to the .vimrc file, i suppose?

Answer (score 2):

I removed all the code that wasn't necessary from netrw and ended up with only one line of code:

```
nnoremap <silent> gx :execute 'silent! !xdg-open ' . shellescape(expand('<cWORD>'), 1)<cr>
```

This achieves the same as netrw, only better. Replace `xdg-open` with `open` in macOS, and `start` in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty late to this party, but here's another way of doing this that works especially well on Windows 7.

1. **Install both [vim-shell](https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell) and [vim-misc](https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc) in vim** I recommend doing this via ever-awesome [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) plugin and then simply `cd ~/vimfiles/bundle & git clone git@github.com:xolox/vim-misc.git & git clone git@github.com:xolox/vim-shell.git` from msysgit. (*These two plugins open urls in your default browser without creating any extra command prompts or other silly nonsense usually required in windows. You can open urls in Vim like this: `:Open http://duckduckgo.com`. Try it. You'll like it.*)
2. **Create some vim mappings** so that you can quickly get the line under the cursor into the browser. I'd map this to u (for me, that's `,u` from normal mode). Here's how:

   nnoremap u :exec "Open ".getline(".")

To use this mapping, type your Leader key from normal mode + u. It should read the line under your cursor and open it in your default browser.

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS user:

`nmap <silent> gx :!open <cWORD><cr>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a netrw-independent solution for neovim implemented in lua that uses `<cfile>` instead of `<C-r><C-a` so that it works for URLs surrounded by non-whitespace characters. All this is done asynchronously using `jobstart` so nvim isn't blocked while the external process tries to open `<cfile>`. If the invoked program, for whatever reason, still runs after 5 seconds, it is killed using `jobstop`.

On windows it effectively uses `cmd /c start <cfile>` so it opens all kinds of files/URLS with the system-associated app. However, if no associated default-app is found, or the file doesn't exist, Windows tries to show a modal dialog, waiting for user input indefinitely. This dialog is hidden so the process would just linger in the background forever for no reason. This was the main reason for using `jobstop`.

```lua
local function open_external(file)
    local sysname = vim.loop.os_uname().sysname:lower()
    local jobcmd
    if sysname:match("windows") then
        jobcmd = ("start %s"):format(file)
    else
        -- Note sure if this is correct. I just copied it from the other answers.
        jobcmd = { "open", file }
    end
    local job = vim.fn.jobstart(jobcmd, {
        -- Don't kill the started process when nvim exits.
        detach = true,

        -- Make relative paths relative to the current file.
        cwd = vim.fn.expand("%:p:h"),
    })
    -- Kill the job after 5 seconds.
    local delay = 5000
    vim.defer_fn(function()
        vim.fn.jobstop(job)
    end, delay)
end
vim.keymap.set("n", "gx", function()
    open_external(vim.fn.expand("<cfile>"))
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a quick look to this vim plugin

[henrik/vim-open-url](https://github.com/henrik/vim-open-url)

It's basically what has been explained in some other responses, but specific configuration needed if you use a plugin manager :)

Answer (score 0):

[As described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458887/1904943) above by [@kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348785/kevh), modified for Linux environments.

Aside: when this function was executed (Vim 8.1) in my terminal, the Vim screen was obfuscated (mostly "blanked;" i.e., the text was there but not visible).  The `:redraw!` command (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1117742/1904943) redraws the screen.

Add to `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap <leader>g :call Google()<CR>:redraw!<CR>
fun! Google()
  let keyword = expand("<cword>")
  let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . keyword
  let path = "/usr/bin/"
  exec 'silent !"' . path . 'firefox" ' . url
endfun
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, just replace "start" with whatever your OS uses

GU for **go url!**

```
" Open url
if (has('win32') || has('win64'))
   nmap gu :exec "!start <cWORD>"<cr> 
else
   nmap gu :exec "!open <cWORD>"<cr> 
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

### macOS searching google for keyword.

I slightly changed @kev solution to implement the same on Mac,

```sh
nmap <leader>gw :call Google()<CR>
fun! Google()
    let keyword = expand("<cword>")
    let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . keyword
    let path="/Applications/Firefox.app"
    "exec 'silent ! path url'
    silent exec "!open -a ".path." '".url."'" | redraw!
endfun
```

if you are using Lua.init, wrap the function using

```sh
local cmd = vim.cmd 
cmd [[
nmap <leader>gw :call Google()<CR>
fun! Google()
    let keyword = expand("<cword>")
    let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . keyword
    let path="/Applications/Firefox.app"
    "exec 'silent ! path url'
    silent exec "!open -a ".path." '".url."'" | redraw!
endfun
]]
```

#### Note

To use `Safari` instead use
`let path="/Applications/Safari.app"`

Answer (score 0):

There are good ideas about starting a search from vim, here is a command implementation :

```
""" Browser
command! -bar -nargs=1 S call Google(<q-args>)
function! Google(search) range
  let url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . a:search
  exec '!firefox-developer-edition "' . url . '"'
endfunction
```

Usage :

```
:S film tom medina
```