# vim does not go back to the same file when exit from external command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to compile my tex file inside vim. I have a Makefile to do the compilation, and I just type `:make` to call it. Usually it works well, but sometimes vim does not go back to the .tex file where I called make. Instead, I find I'm in a .cls file after pressing "ENTER or type command to continue".

I wonder what's happening? And how to make it work as I expected -- going back to the original file? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Vim found some errors in your code and tries to be helpful by jumping to the related file and line. According to `:help make` you should be able to avoid that by using `:make!` (notice the exclamation mark) instead:

`If [!] is not given the first error is jumped to.`

Answer (score 2):

You can also call `:make` and let it open the file with the first error, then jump back to the original file by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is another question that might be related: [How do I disable the "Press ENTER or type command to continue" prompt in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890802/how-do-i-disable-the-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-prompt-in-vim)

I am using this configuration:

```
map <F10> :w<CR>:!make<CR><CR>
```

Pressing F10 key in normal mode saves me the tex file and calls make and returns to editing the file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I actually encounter that question when searching Google before posting this question. Pressing ENTER to go back is fine with my. My problem is that I can not go back to the original file.