# Cannot disable "Press ENTER or type command to continue" message

Tags: vim

I have the following command:

`command! FilesUpdateMRU :execute '!${MYSCRIPTS}/file -m'`

The script executes and at the end I see the following message:

`Press ENTER or type command to continue`

This is expected, but I want to disable this message. I know there are already [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890802/how-do-i-disable-the-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-prompt-in-vim) with this kind of discussion and I have read them and tried the following:

- `set cmdheight=2`
- `set shortmess+=F` and and `set shortmess=F` and `set shortmess=` and `set shortmess=a set syntax=on`

None of this helps, vim waits for me to press a key. The only thing that helps is *silent+redraw*:

`command! FilesUpdateMRU2 :silent execute '!${MYSCRIPTS}/file -m' | redraw!`

The question is: how do I figure out the reason and get away from this message? It looks like I am missing something.

My `.vimrc`:

```
set cmdheight=2
set shortmess=
set nomore
set formatoptions-=cro

command! FilesUpdateMRU :execute '!${MYSCRIPTS}/file -m'
command! FilesUpdateMRU2 :silent execute '!${MYSCRIPTS}/file -m' | redraw!
```

Environment:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 10 2020 20:32:49)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-2292
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `:help press-enter`:

```
This message is given when there is something on the screen for you to read,
and the screen is about to be redrawn:
- After executing an external command (e.g., ":!ls" and "=").
[...]
```

Basically, you will still get that message as long as you print the output of the external command. If you don't care about that output, then you can simply `:help :call` `:help system()`:

```
command! FilesUpdateMRU :call system('${MYSCRIPTS}/file -m')
```

which executes the external command without echoing its output.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you did with `:silent` is right,

check help page `:help :!`

> Vim redraws the screen after the command is finished,
> because it may have printed any text.  This requires a
> hit-enter prompt, so that you can read any messages.
> **To avoid this use:** >
> :silent !{cmd}
> <           The screen is not redrawn then, thus you have to use
> CTRL-L or ":redraw!" if the command did display
> something.
> Also see |shell-window|.