# Vim for windows: How can I prevent a powershell based command from forcing me to exit out of Vim and pressing enter

Tags: powershell, vim

I'm running vim for windows in a Powershell 7 terminal. I'd like to make my own command, called `SB` that would do the following:

1. Save the current file
2. Run the script `build.ps1`

So I added the following to my `_vimrc` file:

```
command! SB w|!powershell.exe -file .\build.ps1
```

This works OK, but when I run `:SB` the screen clears out and I get the following message:

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I have to press "Enter" to get back to Vim, which is inconvenient since I aim to use `SB` quite a lot.

I found a [potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890802/how-do-i-disable-the-press-enter-or-type-command-to-continue-prompt-in-vim), namely inserting a carriage return after the shell command as follows:

```
command! SB w|!powershell.exe -file .\build.ps1|<CR>
```

But this doesn't work and I get an error:

> ) was unexpected at this time.
>
> shell returned 1
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

I feel like the carriage return could be a good solution to this problem. What am I doing wrong above?

Comment: You should probably use the built-in `:help :terminal`.

Comment: @romainl I don't want to sound passive agressive, but do you think I would be asking the question on here if I hadn't tried all avenues, including that?

Comment: This is Stack Overflow so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To *generalize* your own answer**:

- `silent` is indeed the command that suppresses the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` prompt.

  - However, the primary terminal screen showing the command's output is still switched to for the duration of the command execution, and I haven't found a way to suppress that (`:help :redir` mentions using `silent` with a *function* call, but at least with external commands that doesn't seem to help).
- As `:help :silent` notes (emphasis added):

  - > When using this *for an external command*,
    > this *may cause the screen to be messed up*.
    > Use |CTRL-L| to clean it up then.
  - The command equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> is `:redraw!`

Therefore:

```
command! SB w | silent exe '!powershell.exe -file ./build.ps1' | redraw!
```

---

As for **what you originally tried**:

> I found a [potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/890802/45375), namely inserting a carriage return after the shell command as follows:
> `command! SB w|!powershell.exe -file .\build.ps1|<CR>`

Using `<CR>` in the way you intend only works in the context of a `:map` command, where you essentially define a string to send to VIM as if it had been typed interactively.

By contrast, in your case `|<CR>` was simply considered *part of the shell command* (`|`), which caused a *syntax error*.

Therefore, you *could* do something like the following with `:map` (using a simplified example) - but there's no good reason to do so, given that `:silent` is the right solution, as shown above:

```
map <F5> :!whoami<CR><CR>
```

Afterwards, if you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, `whoami` executes, and the *second* `<CR>` then auto-responds to the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` prompt and in effect returns to VIM's edit buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

`command! SB w | silent exec "!powershell.exe -file .\\build.ps1"`

It still exits out of the screen, but at least gets me back to it automatically without any fuss.